# How can I clear apt-mark remove list?

Tags: apt, package-management

In an attempt to `unhold` a package, I ran `sudo apt-mark remove php*` instead of `sudo apt-mark unhold php*` and now my system has marked PHP for uninstall. How can I stop PHP from being removed the next time `apt-get update` is ran? There doesn't appear to be an `apt-mark unremove` command, or anything I can find via Google. Is there a way to stop this from running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply hold the packages again, this will remove them from the removal-list:

```
sudo apt-mark hold php*
```

Here an example that shows that it works, I just picked the package `kmines` for this example:

```
~$ sudo apt-mark hold kmines
kmines set on hold.
~$ apt-mark showhold kmines
kmines
~$ sudo apt-mark remove kmines
Selected kmines for removal.
~$ apt-mark showremove kmines
kmines
~$ sudo apt-mark hold kmines
kmines set on hold.
~$ apt-mark showhold kmines
kmines
~$ apt-mark showremove kmines
~$
```

As you can see, the package is not listed for removal anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above an `apt-mark install` for the php would work for a command. This would have put it in an install state obviously. Use `man apt-mark` in this specific case to get the instructions and options for a program. Should give you better results than Google for it.